# ZEND Application not playing Videos

Tags: php, zend-framework, video

I am building a we in ZEND, but the problem is when I upload video file and access it by path like this: `example/videos/1/vid.mp4`, it is not playing the videos and access the other format files like `.mp3`, `.pdf` on the same path, like this totally accessible 
`example/videos/1/document.pdf` or `example/videos/1/song.mp3`.

I searched a lot but can't find any thing useful or helpful.

Comment: what version of Zend, where are you placing these files in your file structure?

Comment: Maybe you should access the path by starting with a "/"?

Comment: I tried on both framework1 and framework2

Comment: where I put "/" this?

Comment: You need to post your code.  Period.

Comment: i think this is not the problem of code as browser is playing the videos if place the videos in non-zend application and run that application.

Comment: When you click on the web to access video, what error gives to you?

Comment: it redirect me to the login page, plus 302 found status showed in network.